# Glob as the argument of a shell function

Tags: function, shell, parameter-passing, zsh

I'm writing a reusable function, so I need the argument to be as flexible as possible.

Consider a simple example:

```
function testf(){
    print ./*.$1
}
```

This works. For example, with `testf mp3` it lists all the files ending with `.mp3` in an array, making possible the use of `for` loops. But this way it only allows me to work with the extension name.

Therefore, I tried:

```
function testf(){
    print ./$1
}
```

However, it doesn't work. Using `testf *.mp3`, unlike using `print *.mp3` in the terminal, it will only pass the first matching string instead of the whole array.

Any suggestion?

Comment: `*.mp3` is a glob, not a regex.

Comment: @Wiktor But when using `./0[3-6]*.mp3` instead, it shouldn't be a regex?

Comment: It depends on what you think `*` does. At any rate, this is not a question about a regex.

Comment: `./0[3-6]*.mp3` is both a legal glob *and* a legal regular expression, but they mean different things. The shell will treat it as a glob; if it is passed as a pure string (by quoting it to prevent shell expansion) it will be treated as whatever the program receiving it expects.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for pointing me out, I didn't know that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*ists all the files ending with .mp3 in an array*  ... there is no array involved in your question.

But to your problem: First, you want to pass to your function a wildcard pattern, but this is not what you are actually doing. `testf *.mp3` expands the pattern **before** the function is invoked (this process is called filename generation), and your `testf` gets just a list of files as parameters. You **can** pass a pattern, but you have to ask the shell not to expand it:

```
testf '*.mp3'
```

In this case, your `$1` indeed will contain the string `*.mp3`.  However, your `print ./$1` will still not work. The reason is that filename generation occurs before parameter expansion (which is the process where `$1` is replaced by the string it contains). Again, you have to ask the shell to do it the other way round:

```
print ./${~1}
```

Answer (score 0):

The shell performs several types of expansions **before** launching the command. When you enter

```sh
testf *.mp3
```

the shell will expand the glob first, and pass each filename as a separate argument to the function

Your function could look like this:

```
function testf(){
    printf './%s\n' "$@"
}
```

Comment: `$@` expands to all parameters. Is it possible to make it ignore the first parameter but executing the rest?

Comment: The standard way would be to execute `shift` first, to discard the first parameter. `bash` lets you use `"${@:1}"` as an alternative that doesn't modify the value of `$@`.